# Why am I missing the symbol "_xmlNodeListGetString" when using the PayPal API?

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal

When I add the PayPal API to my iPhone application, I'm seeing the following errors:

```
  "_xmlNodeListGetString", referenced from:
  "_inflateInit_", referenced from:
  "_xmlSetProp", referenced from:
```

What could be the cause of these?

Comment: apple won't allow this in the approval process.

Comment: also can you explain some more about what you are trying to do and show some code?

Comment: yes sure i am add paypal api,s in my project and i also import them when i use there code then it give referance error ...i think they will not get framework.it gives error which i wrote above

Comment: Your target is not properly linked to the correct source files/libraries/frameworks.

Comment: @Daniel It will only be rejected if paypal is used for in-app-purchase. Paypal for everything else won't be rejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to add the "-lxml2" flag to your Linker flags and "/usr/include/libxml2" to the Header Search Paths

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing the libxml2 framework.

1. Right Click on the `Frameworks` Group in the xcode sidebar
2. Choose `Add/Existing Frameworks...`
3. Select libxml2.dylib in the framework list that just opened.
4. Hit Add
5. Rebuild project